# print a file in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, printing, network-printers

```
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE; //  FILE IS .txt TYPE
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
//pras.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
//pras.add(new Copies(1));

PrintService printService[] =PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
System.out.println("Print Service:"+printService);

PrintService defaultService =PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
System.out.println("Default Service:"+defaultService);
PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 200, 200,printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);

if (service != null) 
{
    System.out.println("Selected Service"+service);
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
    job.addPrintJobListener(new MyPrintJobListener());

    System.out.println("JOB:"+job);
    DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, das);

    System.out.println("Start of Print");
    job.print(doc, pras);
    System.out.println("End of Print");
    i=1;
}
else
{
    i=0;
}
```

I'm Working on a web application where the user wishes to print the data which is saved in file which contains details from database as per his query.I'm placing the above code in a method and when this is invoked it gives a print dialog for user where he can select the printer from list of printers attached to his machine.
If i try to print to a local printer the files are being sent to  C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool folder and goes for printing.
but it does not happen in the case of a network printer
my printer on the network is Canon MP280 series Printer 
i'm able to see it in list of printer,but unable to print my file

Answer (score 0):

the printer on the network is share or not?
if the printer is shared and in your pc / laptop has installed. 
you must choice one of list array of print service name

e.g

```
PrintService defaultPrintservice = printServices[0];
```

if the printer not install in your PC / Laptop, you must set the path of location network printer

e.g

```
new PrinterName("ipp:\\\\witnw21va\\ipp\\ITDepartment-HP4050", null);
```

i hope it solve your problem :) sorry for my english :D